# Add variable without losing formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to click on the variable, it is added at the position indicated by the cursor without losing the formatting.

This function has hours that works, has hours that do not, it seems that it has its own volition ..

Editor before adding the variable:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhzfN.jpg

After adding the variable:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOM3j.jpg

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t-_bJL0HCh-c5y4uNQQlhOji8y_KlcPr/view

The variable does not stay where it was marked to be inserted and the text still loses formatting.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($("#editor1").text() == "") {
      $("#editor1").text($(this).html());
    } else {
      $("#editor1").text($("#editor1").text() + $(this).html());
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor1" name="name" rows="8" cols="80">
TERMO CONTRATUAL

CONTRATADO: AAAAA, razão social: AAAAA, pessoa jurídica de direito privado, inscrita no CNPJ/MF sob o nº AAAAAA, estabelecida à AAAAAA; 

CONTRATANTE e/ou ALUNO: 

</textarea>
<br>
<small>ALUNO...:
- <a href="#" title="Rua" class="button"> $sAlunoRua</a>
- <a href="#" title="Numero" class="button"> $sAlunoNumero</a>
- <a href="#" title="Bairro" class="button"> $sAlunoBairro</a>
- <a href="#" title="Cidade" class="button"> $sAlunoCidade</a>
</small>
```

Comment: Use `.val()` instead of `.text()` on inputs and textareas.

Comment: @StackSlave Hello, edit the text and place variables in other places.

Comment: @StackSlave See images (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhzfN.jpg) and (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOM3j.jpg)

Comment: Hard to understand your question. Code works as expected for me.

Comment: @StackSlave Please, see this video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t-_bJL0HCh-c5y4uNQQlhOji8y_KlcPr/view

Comment: @StackSlave You see?

Comment: I'm using chrome

Comment: Are you using a CMS?

Comment: @StackSlave I make my dashboard, html, css, js, php

Comment: @StackSlave Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: You update your code through your website dashboard, not FileZilla?

Comment: I use ATOM, when saved it automatically sends the file to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to get the value on your cursor position. I refered [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110102112946/http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/425/how-to-insert-text-into-a-textarea-where-the-cursor-is/) and updated your code as below.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textareaid" name="name" rows="8" cols="80">
TERMO CONTRATUAL

CONTRATADO: AAAAA, razão social: AAAAA, pessoa jurídica de direito privado, inscrita no CNPJ/MF sob o nº AAAAAA, estabelecida à AAAAAA; 

CONTRATANTE e/ou ALUNO: 

</textarea>
    <br>
        - <a href="#" title="Rua" class="button" onclick="insertAtCaret('textareaid', '$sAlunoRua');return false;">$sAlunoRua</a>
        - <a href="#" title="Numero" class="button" onclick="insertAtCaret('textareaid', '$sAlunoNumero');return false;">$sAlunoNumero</a>
        - <a href="#" title="Bairro" class="button" onclick="insertAtCaret('textareaid', '$sAlunoBairro');return false;">$sAlunoBairro</a>
        - <a href="#" title="Cidade" class="button" onclick="insertAtCaret('textareaid', '$sAlunoCidade');return false;"> $sAlunoCidade</a>
        
<script>
       
        function insertAtCaret(areaId, text) {
            var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId);
            if (!txtarea) {
                return;
            }

            var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
            var strPos = 0;
            var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ?
              "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false));
            if (br == "ie") {
                txtarea.focus();
                var range = document.selection.createRange();
                range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
                strPos = range.text.length;
            } else if (br == "ff") {
                strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;
            }

            var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0, strPos);
            var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos, txtarea.value.length);
            txtarea.value = front + text + back;
            strPos = strPos + text.length;
            if (br == "ie") {
                txtarea.focus();
                var ieRange = document.selection.createRange();
                ieRange.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
                ieRange.moveStart('character', strPos);
                ieRange.moveEnd('character', 0);
                ieRange.select();
            } else if (br == "ff") {
                txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
                txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
                txtarea.focus();
            }

            txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
        }
    </script>
```